# Sent an email- getting permanent failure - When does this actually happen and why?

Tags: email, gmail

I have sent repeated emails to a person but it hasn't reached. What might be the problem.

### This is what I received on gmail.

1)

```
This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification

THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.

YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.

Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:

     recepient's email

Message will be retried for 2 more day(s)

Technical details of temporary failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain gmail.com by gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [2607:f8b0:400c:c03::1a].

The error that the other server returned was:
452-4.2.2 The email account that you tried to reach is over quota. Please direct
452-4.2.2 the recipient to
452 4.2.2 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6558 sm10si7159309vec.119 - gsmtp

----- Original message -----

Return-Path: 
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of (my email) designates 10.221.26.10 as permitted sender) client-ip=10.221.26.10
Authentication-Results: mr.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of ----(my email) designates 10.221.26.10 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=(my email);
       dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com
X-Received: from mr.google.com ([10.221.26.10])
        by 10.221.26.10 with SMTP id rk10mr14179914vcb.0.1393275384234 (num_hops = 1);
        Mon, 24 Feb 2014 12:56:24 -0800 (PST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to:content-type;
        bh=6eTtu8ICdKZVe1dJzW7SGKRg6OmQufA9APuGZtOvfQc=;
        b=eTpiROB4Z6HS911hH1Hb7i4683rExRl+PfiQiAniTSLp/RSEH1Sip7SeP06t3KDgL/
         CdMbE/L5SGIyQKuUcEIU8/WyoQWiL6+m3u3eZpKc4e+uZroN52lz52eVhqtvhCERJ9QK
         1qlNf8YWBHT1D/6r1g6iLUqfrbYfOKC2qHTdS/LdCJlrN5mgRyCmC/40zVYYx2Cqgos8
         aNe7N8s/e3YLADPFitMl/C1i+47FNjI7k5HqpCm2L3mbaF3rD6PpGVPI6zSc3K/kh7Q1
         7AppwNE2TPmVSWAhmiXIrOl98xmUtif1Iy08kdDdscghQwGmYhRLijswesj6lQ4ONoKy
         AImg==
X-Received: by 10.221.26.10 with SMTP id rk10mr14179914vcb.0.1393275384057;
 Mon, 24 Feb 2014 12:56:24 -0800 (PST)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.52.69.175 with HTTP; Mon, 24 Feb 2014 12:56:02 -0800 (PST)
From: Me
Date: Tue, 25 Feb 2014 02:26:02 +0530
Message-ID: 
Subject: ----
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=001a11339ae459ac2904f32d34ed
```

---

2)

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     recepient's email

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain gmail.com by gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [2607:f8b0:400c:c01::1a].

The error that the other server returned was:
452-4.2.2 The email account that you tried to reach is over quota. Please direct
452-4.2.2 the recipient to
452 4.2.2 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6558 or7si1229648vcb.136 - gsmtp



----- Original message -----

Return-Path: 
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of my email designates 10.221.26.10 as permitted sender) client-ip=10.221.26.10
Authentication-Results: mr.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of my email designates 10.221.26.10 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=my email;
       dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com
X-Received: from mr.google.com ([10.221.26.10])
        by 10.221.26.10 with SMTP id rk10mr14179914vcb.0.1393275384234 (num_hops = 1);
        Mon, 24 Feb 2014 12:56:24 -0800 (PST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to:content-type;
        bh=6eTtu8ICdKZVe1dJzW7SGKRg6OmQufA9APuGZtOvfQc=;
        b=eTpiROB4Z6HS911hH1Hb7i4683rExRl+PfiQiAniTSLp/RSEH1Sip7SeP06t3KDgL/
         CdMbE/L5SGIyQKuUcEIU8/WyoQWiL6+m3u3eZpKc4e+uZroN52lz52eVhqtvhCERJ9QK
         1qlNf8YWBHT1D/6r1g6iLUqfrbYfOKC2qHTdS/LdCJlrN5mgRyCmC/40zVYYx2Cqgos8
         aNe7N8s/e3YLADPFitMl/C1i+47FNjI7k5HqpCm2L3mbaF3rD6PpGVPI6zSc3K/kh7Q1
         7AppwNE2TPmVSWAhmiXIrOl98xmUtif1Iy08kdDdscghQwGmYhRLijswesj6lQ4ONoKy
         AImg==
X-Received: by 10.221.26.10 with SMTP id rk10mr14179914vcb.0.1393275384057;
 Mon, 24 Feb 2014 12:56:24 -0800 (PST)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.52.69.175 with HTTP; Mon, 24 Feb 2014 12:56:02 -0800 (PST)
From: 
Date: Tue, 25 Feb 2014 02:26:02 +0530
Message-ID: 
Subject: subject
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=001a11339ae459ac2904f32d34ed

[Email body]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you the error in the message.

> The email account that you tried to reach is over quota.

That email inbox is full. There isn't anything that you can do except to call the person whom you're trying to send an email to and let them know that they need to remove some of their emails.

Answer (score 1):

It is evident from the error: *452-4.2.2 The email account that you tried to reach is over quota.* that the recipient's mailbox is full.